# When getting arguments of a function, is it fine to use Object.keys().map()?

Tags: javascript

I know there are many ways to do this, but is there a reason to not do something like:

```
var args = Object.keys(arguments).map(i => arguments[i]);
```

vs

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create a copy?

Comment: yeah i want to add an argument inside of the function, so I am just wondering.  both will return new array so just curious

Comment: The first approach will create a new array, surely you can do that

Comment: Is that preferable to the 2nd way?  Just trying to understand if there is some difference under the hood or something.  THanks

Comment: I don't think there is any difference in how you are using them. `map` provides access to the current index and the entire list in each call, while `slice` can include less items than the original array.